# Pydrake Mosek solver update

Tags: drake, mosek

I am using Mosek solver to solve MIQPs within PyDrake, but Mosek fatal errors occur for some random instances.

MOSEK fatal error stoptask 
Version : 10.0.18 
File    : src/prslv/checkpro.c 
Line    : 7369 
Msg     : Assertion failed at src/prslv/checkpro.c(7369).

MOSEK fatal error stopenv 
Version : 10.0.18 
Platform: Linux/64-X86 
File    : src/prslv/checkpro.c 
Line    : 7369 
Msg     : Assertion failed at src/prslv/checkpro.c(7369).

I reached out to Mosek and they told me to upgrade Mosek to the latest version 10.1.20. My current version is the default version (10.0.18) I got when I installed PyDrake.

Is it possible to manually update Mosek by myself without affecting any other PyDrake files?

Comment: I added a github issue https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/issues/20628, we will upgrade Drake's Mosek version.

Comment: BTW, Drake's Mosek version has been upgraded to 10.1 https://github.com/RobotLocomotion/drake/pull/20634. It will also be included in the next release of Drake.