# Update PyDrake to the most recent version

Tags: drake, mosek

I built PyDrake from the source in my Linux machine, as I am using Gurobi solver.
How can I update PyDrake to the latest version or upgrade a solver (Mosek or Gurobi) to another version? Do I have to reinstall Pydrake from scratch? Or is there simpler way to do this?

My current problem is that I need to upgrade Mosek to the latest version 10.1, but the version in the PyDrake is Mosek 10.0.18, which was the default version when I installed Pydrake. Now, it is updated to 10.1 ([Pydrake Mosek solver update](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77602226/19456305)), so I want to update my this change to my PyDrake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I built PyDrake from the source in my Linux machine, as I am using Gurobi solver. How can I update PyDrake to the latest version or upgrade a solver (Mosek or Gurobi) to another version? Do I have to reinstall Pydrake from scratch?

Yes.  If you are using Drake (or pydrake) by building and installing it [from source](https://drake.mit.edu/from_source.html#building-the-python-bindings), then in order to use an updated version of Drake you need to checkout (or pull) a different version of the Drake source, and run the install again.

Note in particular this caution in the install docs:

> For any kind of larger change (e.g., upgrading to a newer Drake), we strongly advise that you delete the prior tree (within the install sub-directory) before running `make`.